# Constant current controller for a 5V, 400A supply

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, constant-current

I'm a grad student with some practical experience in electronics but very little foundational understanding. I have a new project that requires a low voltage and high current (5V, 400A) and I've sourced a suitable SMPS. However, it also requires reasonably precise control of the current, and I'm not entirely sure how to do this. I've built constant current power supplies before for low-current applications, but I imagine dealing with 400A is a whole different beast and I want to learn more before I start putting things together as I'm aware that this can be very dangerous.

The following image is a current controller I have put together before. I'd like to do something similar but am not sure how to scale it to high current.

[image]

Does anyone have any recommendations for resources I can read to better understand how to implement this? Also, just for everyone's peace of mind, I am very conscious of the safety risk here and am taking many precautions to protect myself and my surroundings.

Comment: Are you sure you want regulate 400A linear? Even 1V drop on transistor make 400W of heat.

Comment: Is there a better way to control the output of a 5V, 400A SMPS?

Comment: You did not mention what is the supply voltage?

Comment: The supply voltage is 5V

Comment: a SMPS can just as easily supply a constant current, as a constant voltage, with no loss of efficiency, as long as it is designed to, or modified to. It sounds like you haven't sourced a suitable SMPS. What's the load, what are its dynamics, what are max and min voltage you need to supply to it?

Comment: The load will be a wide variety of material samples; as they heat up, their resistance typically drops, leading to high current draw. I think the minimum voltage would probably be as low as 0.3-0.5V, and the maximum voltage should be about 8V but I cannot afford that much power on my breaker.

Comment: Just buy one COTS?

Comment: @king_geedorah What are you thinking about in terms of connecting the material samples? Even a couple of unknown/unaccounted milloohms at that kind of current leads to significant dissipation and voltage drop. And what is the rate of change of the current as the material heats up? I suspect the entire physical design needs to be exposed to view. This can't be handled with fantasy-land schematics using ideal wires and where you have `very little foundational understanding.`

Comment: Did you do any math? 5V 400A is 2000W. That is about the limit that one can draw safely from a european 230V circuit - in US you need to use the 240V high power appliance outlets (or directly design for 3-phase commercial power). Very much out of scope for a simple post here. For comming high current power designs, look how modern GPUs supply their cores.

Comment: 5V @400A is very likely the wrong approach. What exactly are you trying to power?